# BUILD SUCCESSFUL but tests are not executed | Android Studio, Java, TestNG, Gradle, Appium

Tags: java, automation, testng, appium

I have this framework that I build on Android Studio that uses java, TestNG, appium, gradle and so on.

Whenever I run a task that supposedly runs the tests, the build is successful, but the tests are not actually executed. Even the gradle report is updated. I am also using an android emulator to run the tests.

My project is an Android project and not a Java project.

Here is the project structure:

```
project-root
│
├── .gradle
├── .idea
├── app
│   ├── apk
│   ├── build
│   ├── reports
│   ├── screenshots
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   │   ├── com
│       │   │   │   ├── utils
│       │   │   │   │   └── (some classes)
│       │   │   │   └── instagrid
│       │   │   │       └── application
│       │   │   │           └── (some classes - test steps)
│       │   │   └── res
│       │   └── test
│       │       ├── java
│       │       │   └── regression
│       │       │       ├── (your test classes)
│       │       │       └── regression.xml
│       │       └── res
├── gradle
└── (other project files)
```

Here is my regression.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="instagrid" preserve-order="true">
    <test name="Regression">
        <classes>
            <class name="regression.LandingPageTests"/>
            <class name="regression.RegistrationTests"/>
            <class name="regression.LoginTests"/>
            <class name="regression.ProfileTests"/>
            <class name="regression.BatteryDetailsTests"/>
            <class name="regression.MapTests"/>
            <class name="regression.TranslationsTests"/>
            <class name="regression.HomePageTests"/>
            <!--<class name="regression.PairingTests"/>-->
       </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

apply from: "testsetup.gradle"

android {
    namespace 'com.example.instagrid'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.instagrid"
        minSdk 33
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        test.java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        test.resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/res']
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'io.appium:java-client:7.3.0'
    implementation 'org.testng:testng:7.4.0'
    testImplementation project(path: ':app')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // Other dependencies
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.16.1'
}

task smokeTests(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = true
        includeGroups 'smoke'
    }
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching 'regression.xml'
    }
}
```

Here is my testsetup.gradle:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

ext {
    env = 'uat'
    defaultTestPackage = "regression"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    classpath += files (
            android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs,
            android.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs
    )
    useTestNG() {
        includeGroups project.hasProperty("groups") ? "$groups" : "none"
    }
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
        events  = [TestLogEvent.STARTED,
                   TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                   TestLogEvent.PASSED,
                   TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                   TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT,
                   TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR]
        exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showCauses = true
        showExceptions = true
        showStackTraces = true
        showStandardStreams = true

        afterTest { desc, result ->
            println "\nTest executed ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
        }

        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                def output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
                def startItem = '|  ', endItem = '  |'
                def repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                println('\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n' + startItem + output + endItem + '\n' + ('-' * repeatLength))
            }
        }
    }

    enableAssertions = true
    scanForTestClasses = false

    options {
        systemProperties(System.getProperties())
        systemProperty 'env', System.properties['env'] ?: "${env}"
    }
}

def generateTestRunArgs() {
    def resultDir = "$projectDir/app/reports"
    def suiteDir = "$projectDir/src/test/java/regression"
    def regressionXML = "$projectDir/src/test/java/regression.xml"

    def args = ["-d", resultDir, "-configfailurepolicy", "continue", regressionXML]

    if (project.hasProperty("defaultListeners")) {
        args += ["-usedefaultlisteners", "true"]
    } else {
        args += ["-usedefaultlisteners", "false",
                 "-listener", "testng.listeners.TestExecListener"]
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("groups")) {
        args += ["-groups", "$groups"]
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("testclasses")) {
        args += ["-testclass", "$testclasses"]
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("testmethods")) {
        args += ["-methods", "$testmethods"]
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("parallel")) {
        args += ["-parallel", "$parallel"]
    } else {
        args += ["-parallel", "methods"]
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("threads")) {
        args += ["-threadcount", "$threads"]
        args += ["-suitethreadpoolsize", "$threads"]
    } else {
        args += ["-threadcount", "1"]
        args += ["-suitethreadpoolsize", "1"]
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("dataproviderthreads")) {
        args += ["-dataproviderthreadcount", "$dataproviderthreads"]
    } else {
        args += ["-dataproviderthreadcount", "1"]
    }

    return args
}


/**
 * Using the default gradle test task (limited options)
 * Usage:
 * $ gradle clean testRun --tests FeatureATest
 */
task testRun(type: Test) {
    dependsOn "clean"

    classpath += files(
            android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs,
            android.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs
    )

    scanForTestClasses = true
    forkEvery = 1
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = true
        includeGroups 'smoke'
    }
    testClassesDirs = files("src/test/java/regression")

    doLast {
        def args = generateTestRunArgs()
        println "TestNG args: " + args
        println "System property env value: ${System.properties.env}"
        println "env default: $env"
    }
}

/**
 * Using the default gradle test task (limited options)
 * Usage:
 * $ gradle testGroups -Pgroups=main
 * $ gradle testGroups -Pgroups=main,unit
 */
task testGroups(type: Test) {
    dependsOn "clean", "classes", "testClasses"

    useTestNG() {
        includeGroups project.hasProperty("groups") ? "$groups" : "none"
    }
    testLogging.events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    testLogging.exceptionFormat = "full"
}
```

And the result:

```
./gradlew clean testRun -Pgroups=smoke        

> Task :app:testRun

--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Results: SUCCESS (0 tests, 0 successes, 0 failures, 0 skipped)  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TestNG args: [-d, D:\Workspace\instagrid\app/app/reports, -configfailurepolicy, continue, D:\Workspace\instagrid\app/src/test/java/regression.xml, -usedefaultlisteners, false, -listener, testng.listeners.TestExecListener, -groups, s
moke, -parallel, methods, -threadcount, 1, -suitethreadpoolsize, 1, -dataproviderthreadcount, 1]
System property env value: null
env default: uat
```

Please let me know if you need any more details. I am desperate to make it work, I've literally tried everything, even ChatGPT is confused...

Trying to run the tests with a task that I created, but the tests are not actually executed. The build is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to pass value with system properties:

   ```
   useTestNG() {
      ...
      includeGroups System.getProperty("groups", "none") 
   }
   ```

   Now call lokks like that: `./gradlew clean testRun -Dgroups=smoke`.

   - Use `-D` instead of `-P`!
2. Make sure `scanForTestClasses = false` is properly overwritten in `testRun` task.
3. Ensure using suit file, `regression.xml` in your case:

   ```
   useTestNG() {
      ...
      suites "$projectDir/src/test/java/regression.xml"
   }
   ```

Comment: Updated the code. Called `./gradlew clean testRun -Dgroups=smoke` and the tests still don't start.

Comment: If you put just `includeGroups "smoke"` are you able to run tests?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: In dir tree you sowing that your tests are under "app/src/main/test/java/regression', Is that correct?  path should be "app/src/test/java/regression'

Comment: The tests are in the correct path: "app/src/test/java/regression".

Comment: Maybe you can share link to the project if that is possible? It's hard to debug just looking at text.

Comment: I noticed `scanForTestClasses = false`, It might be overriding settings of `testRun` task

Comment: The link to the project is private unfortunately. I set the scanForTestClasses = true everywhere and still nothing. Here is what I did now: I added this line: `println "Checking if regression.xml exists: ${new File(regressionXML).exists()}"` and it returns true. So it finds the .xml file, but it does not start it...

Comment: Hm, take a look at third option:  add `suites "$projectDir/src/test/java/regression.xml"` to `useTestNG`.  That must be an issue.

Comment: Added, build successful but tests are still not run. I'm hopeless. :(

Comment: Marked java folder under main as source folder and java folder under test as test source folder and now the tests are found with ./gradlew test. However, I am getting this error for all of them:

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)

Let me know if I should paste the Driver class and one Test class for more info.